# How to keep client session alive in spring MVC after server disconnection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session-cookies, session-state

I am working on `Spring MVC` application. Usually face a problem that when server get down the client session get expired.

So, I want to make session alive. When server goes up then client not need to login again.
Can we save cookie id or session id in database to make client reconnect.

Comment: spring security remember me

Comment: @NimChimpsky not exactly remember me. When user into the system an in any case server goes down for a while and again reconnect.

Comment: yeah thats remember me functionality as provided by spring secruity

Answer (score 1):

could it be what you are looking for?

[how-can-i-make-the-spring-security-stores-the-http-session-in-database-so-i-can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507749/how-can-i-make-the-spring-security-stores-the-http-session-in-database-so-i-can)

here is the link to the blog-article:

[Tomcat 7 JDBC Session Persistence](http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/21/tomcat-7-jdbc-session-persistence/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring security, you can have your own implementation of SecurityContextRepository (By default this is HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository) to persist the session content in database. In this way when user presents his cookie the security framework filter (SecurityContextPersistentFilter) will look at your database for the session. Hence, even when server is down the context is still available in database and is loaded during next user request after server restart.

If session persistence is not an option, you may have to deploy a cluster of servers with session replication strategy.

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of remember me is altogether different. It's not to have session across server restarts, but for across restarts in client (browser). Even with remember-me you can not get it across server restarts, unless you use PersistentRememberMeService (to database)

Comment: You actually can carry authentication between server restarts with the token based strategy if you set the token to some value that doesn't change. By default, the token gets regenerated on each application start and I guess that's the reason you think it's not possible to make it work.