# How can I do relational database-based HTTP Session Persistence in Spring 4?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to be able to store the HTTP Session in a relational database in order to do stateless load balancing of my front-end users across multiple front-end servers. How can I achieve this in Spring 4?

I see how one can do this with Redis, however there does not appear to be documentation on how to do this with a relational database e.g. Postgres.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507749/how-can-i-make-the-spring-security-stores-the-http-session-in-database-so-i-can

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With Spring Session (it transparently will override HttpSessions from Java EE) you can just take `SessionRepository` interface and implement it with your custom ex. `JdbcSessionRepository`. It is kind of easy to do. When you have your implementation, then just add manually (you don't need `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation) created filter to filter chain, like bellow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   //other stuff...

   @Autowired
   private SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository;

   private HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy = new CookieHttpSessionStrategy(); // or HeaderHttpSessionStrategy

   @Bean
   public SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository() {
       return new JdbcSessionRepository();
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       super.configure(http);
       SessionRepositoryFilter<ExpiringSession> sessionRepositoryFilter = new SessionRepositoryFilter<>(sessionRepository);
       sessionRepositoryFilter.setHttpSessionStrategy(httpSessionStrategy);
       http
            .addFilterBefore(sessionRepositoryFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
   }
}
```

Here you have how `SessionRepository` interface looks like. It has only 4 methods to implement. For how to create Session object, you can look in `MapSessionRepository` and `MapSession` implementation (or `RedisOperationsSessionRepository` and `RedisSession`).

```
public interface SessionRepository<S extends Session> {
   S createSession();
   void save(S session);
   S getSession(String id);
   void delete(String id);
}
```

Example solution https://github.com/Mati20041/spring-session-jpa-repository

Comment: Thanks, can you please complete this with an implementation of the JDBCSessionRepository?

Comment: I can give you later an example made in Spring Data JPA (with SQL Database as Datasource), if that will please you.

Comment: yes, and if u can show what the database table definition is, that would be helpful.

Comment: Here I have uploaded sample solution to your problem, maybe it is not as fancy as it can be, but works. https://github.com/Mati20041/spring-session-jpa-repository . It uses in memory database for the sake of simplicity, but you can change it easily in application.properties.

Comment: Mati, one question, I was implement your code on my App. When I enter for the first time I have 1 cookie "SESSION", but when I login (using spring security) I have the security cookie "JSESSION". This is correct to clustered enviroment? or I need just the JSESSION cookie and store it over the DB?

Comment: When you deal with spring-session, use SESSION, not JSESSION. JSESSION probably comes from server(tomcat, jetty or sth), not spring. If you run my demo, you can see (for example in firefox developer tools -> network) that it does not send JSESSION cookie.

Comment: Hi Mati, thanks for your answer, i have been working session management, and above answer worked for alot, but i am getting this error on browser 'Invalid CSRF Token was found on the request parameter **_csrf or header X-CSRF-TOKEN**

Comment: @Ravi. Hi Ravi, CSRF-TOKEN is (or 'should be' AFAIK) be different kind of problem that is not related to this topic. It is from security package and you can read more about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html or I would suggest this article, which covers how you can handle it in other ways (or just turn it off, but that might be a security flaw) https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii

Comment: Hi Mati, thanks for response, i solved the problem by configuring SecurityIntializer class which is extends to AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer

Comment: I am getting "No qualifying bean of type 'com.fastcheck.timesheet.common.session.SpringSessionRepository' available' error. Am I doing something wrong? Follow the link for source code https://github.com/jpavanaryan/FastCheck/blob/FormLogin/src/main/java/com/fastcheck/timesheet/common/session/SessionRepositoryImpl.java

Answer (score 0):

Now spring boot supports by 'spring-session-jdbc'. You can save session into db with less code. For more example you can look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-jdbc.html#httpsession-jdbc-boot-sample

Answer (score -1):

Just slap Spring Session on it, and you're done. Adding a Redis client bean and annotating a configuration class with `@EnableRedisHttpSession` is all you need.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I dont wish to do this with Redis. I wish to do this in the database I already have, Postgres.

Comment: @BestPractices Specifically avoiding Redis wasn't a particularly clear requirement. That said, I believe Spring Session supports a JDBC repository (and adding one would be trivial if it doesn't).