# Spring-security : session-config with COOKIE not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I want to keep the user logged-in even after Apache Tomcat restarts. I came upon 2 strategies, one with implementing `<session-config>` with `<tracking-mode>` as `COOKIE`, and other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507749/how-can-i-make-spring-security-store-the-http-session-in-a-database-to-use-the-w) was to setup Tomcat to store HTTP Session. We have postgres, and not much information available for how to do this with PostgreSQL.

I tried the first configuration, although I have no errors, whenever I restart tomcat, user is thrown to login. Is this the correct approach to this problem. Any way to do this with Redis? Thank you.

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
  <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/canvaslisting"
                             always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/denied"/>
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                              token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
   <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>-->
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
// we want multi-browser logins. 
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionReg" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionReg" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

web.xml :

```
 <session-config>
        <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linked issue already describes how to persist a session to a JDBC database.
The example uses MySql, the only difference to use Postgres is to change the url and driver class, like you would with any JDBC connection.

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager"
         maxIdleBackup="10">
  <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore"
         connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mytomcat?user=root"
         driverName="org.postgresql.Driver"
         sessionAppCol="app_name"
         sessionDataCol="session_data"
         sessionIdCol="session_id"
         sessionLastAccessedCol="last_access"
         sessionMaxInactiveCol="max_inactive"
         sessionTable="tomcat_sessions"
         sessionValidCol="valid_session" />
</Manager>
```

If you want to use redis, then you can use [Pivotal's `RedisStore` session manager](https://github.com/pivotalsoftware/session-managers).

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager">
    <Store className="com.gopivotal.manager.redis.RedisStore" 
             uri="redis://username:password@localhost:6370/0" />
</Manager>
```

Comment: Any idea of the table and columns required for this to work? Thank you.

Comment: The table name and all the columns are configurable, so its flexible and up to you.  
That said, if you have no need to customize it, you can follow the example laid out in the documentation https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/archive/tc4.0.x/trunk/container/catalina/docs/JDBCStore-howto.html